# How can I modify a specific element(which depends on another dictionary) in a list, where the list is the value of a dictionary? (python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given 2 dictionaries of:

1. the students' id and how many points they've got on each problem:

```
user_probstat_dict = {'106095014': [3, 1, 1], '106095029': [3, 1, 0], '106095033': [3, 1, 0]}
```

2. the students' id and the number of problem that they've been cheated:

```
user_cheatprob_dict = {'106095029': [1, 3], '106095033': [3]}
```

My aim is to change the score into 0 for those problems that have been cheated, like for the id '106095029', this student's original score:

```
'106095029': [3, 1, 0]
```

should be changed into:

```
'106095029': [0, 1, 0]
```

Since maybe not all of the students have cheated, the `user_cheatprob_dict` won't always include all of the student ids.

Here's my code:

```
for u, c in user_cheatprob_dict.items():
    for ci in c:
        prob_ind = ci - 1 
            user_probstat_dict.update({u:???})
```

My thought is to first loop over the `user_cheatprob_dict`, if there's a student that has problems cheated, then take the key (student id = `u`) and use the update function to replace the value into 0.

The `???` in my code is the part where I don't know how to refer to only the specific value(by the index `prob_ind`)in the list.
I only knew that if I want to change the whole value, I just need to place 0 at the `???`part.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 solutions, depending on your needs. Also, those solutions are safe: it won't raise if a student's id is missing in one or another dict, or if a cheated problem's number doesn't correspond to any problem.

**1. Recompute your solution**
This is the more compact one, but it consumes more memory since it recreates a new dictionary. Use it only on small enough samples. The advantage is that you let your input unchanged.

```py
def recompute(points_dict, cheat_dict):
    """create a new points dict, but doesn't modify the input"""
    return {
        idd: [p * ((i + 1) not in cheat_dict.get(idd, [])) for i, p in enumerate(points)]
        for idd, points in points_dict.items()
    }
```

> When multiplied with a number, a boolean corresponds to the value 1 or 0 (respectively for True or False).

**2. Replace directly in the input**
Less compact, but also less memory consumption. And your input is changed!

```py
def replace(points_dict, cheat_dict):
    """replace the points in the input: input modified"""
    for idd, numbers in cheat_dict.items():
        if idd in points_dict:
            for num in numbers:
                if num <= len(points_dict[idd]):
                    points_dict[idd][num - 1] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary traversal as follows:

```
user_probstat_dict = {'106095014': [3, 1, 1], '106095029': [3, 1, 0], '106095033': [3, 1, 0]}
user_cheatprob_dict = {'106095029': [1, 3], '106095033': [3]}

for i in list(user_cheatprob_dict.keys()):
    for j in user_cheatprob_dict[i]:
        user_probstat_dict[i][j-1] = 0
print(user_probstat_dict)
```

**Output:** *Note that the index of user_cheatprob_dict is offset by -1 to get the correct problem index*

```
{'106095014': [3, 1, 1], '106095029': [0, 1, 0], '106095033': [3, 1, 0]}
```